# Using Task<T>.IsFaulted to denote IO failures without propagating exceptions

Tags: c#, task

Before/without `Task<>`s, I'm using a wrapper object like the below to encapsulate the result of an I/O operation that could fail, without propagating exceptions up the call stack:

```
public class FetchResult<T>
{
    public readonly bool Success;
    public readonly T Item;

    public FetchResult(bool success, T item)
    {
        this.Success = success;
        this.Item = item;
    }
}
```

I'd use it like this:

```
var userResult = Get("robert.paulson@fightclub.com");
if(!userResult.Success)
    // abort, or something

...

public FetchResult<User> Get(string email)
{
    try
    {
        // go to database here, and get the User
        return new FetchResult(true, new User());
    }
    catch
    {
        // log exception
        return new FetchResult(false, null);
    }
}
```

This works great for me as a model, as it allows me to effectively manage exceptions without using `try/catch` as program control flow and gives me easy and fine-grained graceful service degredation.

However, with the advent of `Task<>`, I could very easily end up with:

```
    public Task<FetchResult<User>> GetAsync(string email)
```

which seems to be getting out of hand.
Seeing as I'm migrating to `async` everywhere anyway, I'm contemplating just doing:

```
    public Task<User> GetAsync(string email)
```

which id have expected to allow me to do something like:

```
var userTask = GetAsync("robert.paulson@fightclub.com");
await userTask;
if(userTask.IsFaulted) // (*) - see below
    // abort, or something
```

However if my `GetAsync` method returns:

```
return Task<User>.FromException(new Exception());
```

what is actually returned after the await (where the `(*)` comment is) seems to be a Completed `Task`, whos result is a `Task<User>` which is faulted.

Why am I getting a nested task in this case, and is there some syntactic sugar I'm missing to make this whole affair tidier?

Comment: Are you missing the `async` keyword from the definition of `GetAsync`?

Comment: What do you mean by nested task? `Task.FromException` will return a completed task in faulted state having provided exception. The result will be similar as returning your awaited task. Because if the awaited task is faulted then you're creating another faulted task to return. It's the same thing. [update]Unless you're wrapping it with new custom exception.

Comment: What is wrong with `Task<FetchResult<User>>`? If you still don't want to use exceptions, this is the most idiomatic thing to do (IMO). And refactoring will be easy - you will basically just have to add `await` in all the places where you used to call `Get`.

Comment: @kamilk perhaps, doesnt really matter, it returns a task.

Comment: @vendettamit it returns `Task<Task<VoidResult>>`, try it

Comment: @pmbanka, just seems unnecessary, Task has a Status that can be completed or failed. why wrap essentially the same thing in it again?

Comment: @AndrewBullock, because when the task fails, I (as a user of your API) expect it to throw an exception. I would normally wrap call to `GetAsync` with try/catch block. Normally, you don't check for a task failure using `IsFaulted` (although it might come in handy, e.g. in `Task.ContinueWith`). What you want to do will seem like a slight abuse of the Task API. If you want to signal that an async function replaces exceptions with other fault-reporting mechanism, you should do this explicitly - `FetchResult` type seems like a good fit for that. Or - just use exceptions.

Comment: @AndrewBullock Gotcha!! You need to use it like this `Task.FromException<User>(new Exception());`

Comment: @pmbanka Yeah, im not _trying_ to abuse the API, I was asking if i was missing some syntax that could help, if it doesnt work it doesnt work, thats the answer

Comment: @vendettamit sigh. I said this in the question. read it.

Comment: @AndrewBullock I did.. you're missing a point here.. I'll try to add explanation in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two methods in Task library `FromException()` and `FromException<TResult>()` both are available via `Task` and `Task<TResult>`.

```
public static Task FromException(Exception exception)
{
   return FromException<VoidTaskResult>(exception);
}

public static Task<TResult> FromException<TResult>(Exception exception)
{
 ...
 ...
}
```

If you call `Task<TResult>.FromException()` or `Task.FromException()` there's no different in these two calls.

Your method signature is: `public Task<User> GetAsync(string email)`
Now if you try to use `Task<User>.FromException(new Exception())` this will return `Task<VoidTaskResult>` and which is ofcourse is not of type `Task<User>`. Which means you might be getting compiler error.

This compile time error would be gone if you use `Task<User>.FromException<User>(new Exception());` or `Task.FromException<User>(new Exception());`

You're getting `Task<Task<VoidTaskResult>>` as specified in comments means there's something more in your method code which is not mentioned in your sample code.

For more internal details about `Task` methods in .Net source code see [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs,11a386e7d7cae64a)

### Update:

After looking at your code found couple of issues.

i) Return type as Task is avoiding the compilation error that I mentioned earlier in my answer.

ii) You're returning a Task with in a Async method without awaiting means the complete task object will be wrapped in Another Task type.

See below example that I tweaked to to show the problem. See even the return type is changed from Task of type Object to Program there's still no error. This is Because of Object which is base of any custom type in C#. So doing below is allowed:

```
static async Task<object> GetAsync()
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Task.FromException<Program>(e);
    }
}
```

Now change the return type of method to `Task<Program>` you'll get an error or more of warning.[image: Warning CS1998 This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread.]

Now the correct version to fix the problem would be to await the Task so that only Program type remain as result which will be automatically returned as `Task<Program>`.

Correct version:

```
 static async Task<Program> GetAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return await Task.FromException<Program>(e);
            }
        }
```

Now you won't see any Nested tasks anymore. This is internals of how await works. If you really want know why it happens like this then try to analyze the IL generated of all the above 3 versions of the program using IL spy and you'll get the idea. Cheers!!!

Comment: @AndrewBullock I have updated my answer based on given repro gist.

Answer (score 1):

`Task.IsFaulted` means *[that the Task completed due to an unhandled exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted(v=vs.110).aspx)*. So I don't think you could set it in a different way than to let the exception go uncaught.

```
public async Task<User> GetAsync(string email)
{
    // go to database here, and get the User
    return new User();
}
```

Or catch, log, and rethrow:

```
public async Task<User> GetAsync(string email)
{
    try
    {
        // go to database here, and get the User
        return new User();
    }
    catch
    {
        // log exception
        throw;
    }
}
```

I believe you are saying that your `GetAsync` is returning a nested task because you have something like this:

```
public async Task GetAsync(string email)
{
    // .... somewhere in the code
    return Task.FromException(new Exception());
}
```

But when you declare a method using the `async` keyword, C# magic takes care of wrapping its contents inside a `Task`. So in this case you actually end up having a task which returns another task - `Task<Task<T>>`. It would return `Task<T>` if you removed the `async` keyword but then obviously you end up with a standard synchronous method.

Comment: Yeah, it seems an strange choice to define it as "unhandled" only. A task can complete or fail for any number of reasons, why does the mechanism only have the concept of unhandled exceptions?

Comment: @AndrewBullock Well, you can always throw your own exception when you detect an error.

Comment: Because if the code called had handled it, then it wouldn't have failed, by definition.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of unusual, but you can explore the fact that the [Task.WhenAny](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany(v=vs.110).aspx) method does not throw exception (see [Is there a way to Wait for a TPL Task without in throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31917601/is-there-a-way-to-wait-for-a-tpl-task-without-in-throwing-an-exception/31918476#31918476)) like this

```
var userTask = GetAsync("robert.paulson@fightclub.com");
await Task.WaitAny(userTask);
if(userTask.IsFaulted) // (*) - see below
    // abort, or something
```

Comment: Interesting, though presumably the `GetAsync` would need to throw

Comment: I might be missing your point, but w/o this trick your code `if(userTask.IsFaulted)` will never execute because in order to get there, the user task should have successfully completed, otherwise an exception will be thrown.